# XPath the content of current node without children

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How can I choose the content of current node without children nodes with XPath?
for example, if I have like this
`<text> sometext <citation> somecitation </citation> sometext </text>`

so I need just sometext without citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the text in the `text` element, you can use:

```
//text/text()
```

Using e.g. xmllint this gives:

```
> xmllint -xpath "//text/text()" test.xml
 sometext  sometext
```

Comment: //text/text () that is one I was looking for! I need to write xsl that makes sometext and citations in different fonts, maybe you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`text()` gives you all text child nodes, so in XSLT 2.0 you can simply use `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>` to output the two text child nodes. Or write a template

```
<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that in your snippet there are two `text()` child nodes both with `sometext`. It is not clear whether you want to output both.